# Delphi THTTPRIO component on datamodule causes EInvalidPointer

Tags: delphi, soap, free, delphi-2009

In a console application, I placed a THTTPRIO component on a datamodule and invoke a SOAP service - which works as expected, but when the program terminates, an invalid pointer error occurs.

I have tried two ways to call the web service. First used a cast of the THTTPRIO to the soap server interface type

```
HelloService := (DM.HTTPRIO1 as Hello);
Response := HelloService.sayHello('Delphi');
```

As this terminated with an EInvalidPointer exception, I tried the method GetHello in the generated binding unit. The source code below shows this second try.

The error seems to be caused by a double free. How can I access the web service and avoid the double free?

The output in both cases is:

> Server response: Hello, Delphi.
>
> EInvalidPointer: Invalid pointer operation

The datamodul unit code is:

```
unit helloServiceDM;

interface

uses
  helloService,
  Classes, InvokeRegistry, Rio, SOAPHTTPClient;

type
  TDataModule1 = class(TDataModule)
    HTTPRIO1: THTTPRIO;
  public
    class procedure SayHello;
  end;

implementation

uses
  ActiveX, SysUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TDataModule1 }

class procedure TDataModule1.SayHello;
var
  DM: TDataModule1;
  HelloService: Hello;
  Response: string;
begin
  ActiveX.CoInitialize(nil);

  DM := TDataModule1.Create(nil);
  try
    HelloService := GetHello(False, '', DM.HTTPRIO1);
    try
      Response := HelloService.sayHello('Delphi');
      WriteLn('Server response: ' + Response);
    except
      on E:Exception do
        Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    DM.Free;
  end;

  ActiveX.CoUnInitialize;
end;

end.
```

---

p.s.: everything works ok if I create and configure the HTTPRIO instance at runtime. However, this also means all configuration and wiring of event handlers can't be done in the object inspector.

Comment: Your killing me with the DataModule. Is it part of the DataModule or not? Why are you creating a new one? Shouldn't you rather be looking at HTTPRIO1?

Comment: @Sherlock70 the datamodule is used as a container for non-visual components. I create the datamdoule in a class method and within that class method, I can use the THTTPRIO component, so I don't have to configure and wire it dynamically within the source.

Comment: @Sherlock70 the code does not create a "new one" DataModule1 - there is no auto-created instance in this console application

Comment: Got it! Should have noticed "Class function" earlier. Hmmm. I'm sorry, I don't see a problem there...

Comment: try `HelloService := nil;` before the finally.

Comment: @GWimpassinger thank you, this works! (You may add this comment as an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the reference in `HelloService` to the interface `Hello`. This reference go out of scope and is freed at the end of your class method. Your datamodule providing the `THTTPIO` object for the interface is already destroyed in the finally part.

You have to add a `HelloService := nil` before the finally part.

```
DM := TDataModule1.Create(nil);
try
  HelloService := GetHello(False, '', DM.HTTPRIO1);
  try
    Response := HelloService.sayHello('Delphi');
    WriteLn('Server response: ' + Response);
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  HelloService := nil; // <---- Add this
finally
  DM.Free;
end;
```

Comment: However - it is strange that in a VCL application, which uses a THTTPRIO component on a form or datamodule, there is no such exception shown when the program terminates. The nil assignment is not needed. Bonus question: why? ;)

Comment: Because then Delphi takes care of freeing everything.

Comment: @mjn42: who is responsible for the lifetime management of the form or the datamodule?

Comment: I get an `Invalid Pointer operation` in a Win32 VCL application within Delphi 10.3 Rio Community edition too, if I use the same pattern as here. Just put the code in a `ButtonClick` event handler.

Comment: @Sherlock70 I assume that somewhere in the VCL shutdown code, the exception is silently ignored. The VCL uses ownership based memory meanagement, but the web service interface reference is not part of this management (as it has no owner handle).

Comment: @GWimpassinger maybe you can post your code as a new question? Might be a new / different issue which is worth more analysis

Comment: @mjn42: There has been a misunderstanding of my comment about the `Invalid Pointer operation`. I meant that I get an exception with the original code (without `HelloService := nil;`) in a VCL app too. This was a response to your **Bonus question**. For me, there is no "why". I get the same error in the console and in the VCL app.